# Can SSL be used to encrypt non-HTTP data?

Tags: tls

If we have a proprietary binary protocol used by some application, can we use SSL/TLS to encrypt the protocol's payload without tunneling it through HTTP?

Comment: It's a while back since we looked at this, but the SSLeay/OpenSSL demo files came with sample files (`serv.cpp` and `cli.cpp`) from which you can layer SSL (and, presumably, TLS) over a normal socket connection. In essence: you first create a "context" at each end (using the certificate on the server end), then after opening the socket (but before sending any of _your_ data), you add calls to `SSL_connect()` or `SSL_accept()`. It's then mostly a matter of mapping `send()` and `recv()` calls into `SSL_write()` and `SSL_read()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks basic research

Comment: TLS = Transport Layer Security. HTTP is at the application layer, above the transport layer. So yes, of course you can use TLS without HTTP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files

Comment: @paj28 I agree it seems to lack basic research, but StackExchange **is** a source of research for many professionals. Where is the line?

Comment: I think it should stay.  If more people (especially politicians) stopped to wonder whether the same encryption that underpins the world's economy could be used for other purposes, it might stop them trying to ban encryption.

Comment: @david25272 I'm not seeing what this question has to do with that, except that they both involve encryption.

Comment: Technically this is on-topic. It's also a duplicate to our canonical question [How does SSL/TLS work](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/5405).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Can we use SSL/TLS to encrypt the protocol's payload without tunneling it through HTTP?

Absolutely.
TLS provides secure communication on top of the transport layer and you can easily employ it as a transparent wrapper around your own custom protocols.

```
   One advantage of TLS is that it is application protocol independent.
   Higher-level protocols can layer on top of the TLS protocol
   transparently.  The TLS standard, however, does not specify how
   protocols add security with TLS; the decisions on how to initiate TLS
   handshaking and how to interpret the authentication certificates
   exchanged are left to the judgment of the designers and implementors
   of protocols that run on top of TLS.
```

(from [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-1) for TLS 1.2)

HTTP just happens to be one possible application-layer protocol that is commonly transmitted over TLS. There are many other examples where TLS is added to secure a protocol that has no built-in encryption. E.g., if you use a desktop email client, the communication with the mail server (probably using IMAP/POP3/SMTP) will likely be wrapped in TLS, too. TLS can also be used as an encrypted tunnel for the entire network stack for VPN applications (although OpenVPN only uses TLS for authentication, not for for encrypting the actual data - thanks, @ysdx).

Comment: Don't forget IRC!

Comment: AFAIU, OpenVPN does **not** use TLS for encrypting the payload (packets). As explained, in the page you mention, TLS is only used for «  for the authentication and key exchange mechanism » (the control channel). The tunneled packets themselves (the data channel) are not encapsulated in the TLS layer. See https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html, « P_CONTROL_V1 -- Control channel packet (usually TLS ciphertext) » vs « P_DATA_V1 -- Data channel packet containing actual tunnel data ciphertext ».

Answer (score 17):

Yes, TLS can be used for general transport layer security (as the name suggests). A few common uses:

- HTTP (HTTPS)
- FTP (FTPS)
- SMTP (SMTPS)
- VPN

Comment: SMTP (SMTPS) ? smtp normally is unencrypted, right?

Comment: @Brad Yes, but like all the other things on the list, it [can be](https://luxsci.com/blog/smtp-tls-all-about-secure-email-delivery-over-tls.html) secured with TLS.

Comment: Encryption of SMTP data is pretty common on mobile devices